# Method for substracting numbers always returning 48

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method that will take a number (combinaison), and subtract a (coup) from it, char by char. If it's less than 0, the char in questions is 0.

For example, if I have a combination of 333, and I add a "coup" of 142, the result is 201.
Basically, it subtracts every character, one by one, and returns 0 for every negative one.
The 2 inputs must be equal in length or it returns an empty string.

I tried this, but if I enter 1 char, it gives me 48, 2 char 4848, and so on.

### Edit

Solved, I just changed '0' to 0.

```
public static String appliquerCoup(String combinaison, String coup) {
    String res = "";
    if ((combinaison.length() != coup.length()) || (coup.isEmpty())) {
        return res;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < coup.length(); i++) {
            int res2 = (combinaison.charAt(i) - coup.charAt(i));
            if (res2 < '0') {
                res2 = '0';
            }
            res = res + res2;
        }
        return res;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] params) {
    String coup = "3";
    String combinaison = "4";
    String y = appliquerCoup(combinaison, coup);
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

Comment: You know you are using [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) for the subtraction. If you want to use integer subtraction then use int res2 =  Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(combinaison.charAt(i))) - Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(coup.charAt(i)))

Comment: Like @StackFlowed said. The ASCII value for '0' is 48.

Comment: Posting examples of input and expected output (with some corner cases) would be very helpful to understand your question better, which would allow us to give you better answers. If I understood your question correctly simple `if (res2 < 0) { res2 = 0; }` should do the trick. Also you shouldn't be using `string = string + newValue` in a loop, use StringBuilder.

Comment: edit: It worked, i changed the '0' to 0.

I didnt see StringBuilder yet in my class so i can't use it.

but now, when i do res = res + res2,
String = String  + Int, it converts the res to an Int, and my return method should return a String.  ??? I'm confused that it works

Comment: You need to [[edit]] your question and add this informations there. Also add more info about algorithm you are suppose to implement. Like I said earlier examples of input and output (with explanation why such output should be expected) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You know you are using [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) for the subtraction. 
 If you want to use integer subtraction then use

```
int res2 =  Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(combinaison.charAt(i))) - Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(coup.charAt(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the substraction with numbers (int, long, etc) instead of Strings? You can convert the final result to String if you want

```
res = (combinaison - coup).toString();
```

If you don't want to do so:
I think you are wrong in your code, the thing you are substracting is not the number you want, you are substracting the ascii number that correspond to that character.

Comment: You can't subtract Strings in Java.

Comment: I know that but I was saying after converting it to String, or declaring it as int or long initially.